# Storing imprecise dates in sqlite and/or postgres/mysql

Tags: sql, cocoa, sqlite, datetime, date

I'm working on an app that needs to store dates. That's easy. However, the app needs to be able to store dates that are fully formed or missing parts. For instance, the user may have the month and day without a year or the month and year without a day.

Exact language/backend has not been decided but I'll probably create a POC in cocoa/sqlite so we can work with those for an answer.

I considered a three column table with some sort of flag, a DATE/DATETIME column and a TEXT column, but that seems...wrong.

I believe we'll only have to input and show the data, not compare or sort dates, but I'm not entirely sure at this point.

Ideas?

Edit: Thanks to Celada for the suggestions

The idea behind this field is for users to put in dates that likely happened in the past so the precise dates may not be known. For instance, a user may know that an event happened during march 2001 or that a birthday is jan 3, but not the year.

Comment: You probably need to specify a lot more detail about how these timestamps will be used, how they need to to be indexed and compared with one another, etc... But at first glance it seems to be you need 2 timestamps: a start time and and end time, representing a time interval. If the time is known precisely them the two would be the same.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have made an edit.